# mysql_query returns value and null but there should be only value

Tags: php, mysql

i got some null values by returning my `mysql_query` in json notation from php. Some fields, as bookid, name, author, duration are returning values, others not! But i put in the same query in DBVisualizer and i only got value... Whats the problem here?

```
    echo $myuserid . "idcheck";
    $q1 = "select u.address as address, u.postcode as postcode, u.town as town, u.telnumber, u.mail, b.bookid as bookid, b.name as name, b.author as author, s.duration as duration from status s, book b, user u where s.bookid = b.bookid and s.borroweruserid = u.userid and s.borroweruserid = $myuserid";
    echo $q1;
    $sth = mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());

        while($rowla = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {

     $rows[] = array(
      'address' => $rowla['address'],
      'postcode' => $rowla['postcode'],
      'town' => $rowla['town'],
      'telnumber' => $rowla['telnumber'],
      'mail' => $rowla['mail'],
      'bookid' => $rowla['bookid'],
      'name' => $rowla['name'],
      'author' => $rowla['author'],
      'duration' => $rowla['duration']);
     // 'pic' => base64_encode($row['pic']  
    //$rows[] = $r;
       }
       $j1 = json_encode($rows);
```

**UPDATE:** when putting error_reporing to php script nothing works (no query is executed) AND by adding print_r($rowla) after while
Still get this feedback (2nd query is doing the same - just a bit different):
http://s24.postimg.org/4wpu29zwl/Screen_Shot_2014_05_22_at_08_45_02.png

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, if you run `q1` in DBVisualizer, there are no null/empty values shown, but inside `j1` you're getting null/empty values for some fields?

Comment: @asprin, you´re right

Comment: Try putting `error_reporing(E_ALL)` at the top of your php script and see if that prints anything? notice, warning etc..

Comment: @user2554953 : Add `print_r($rowla)` after the while loop, and update the result with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You miss look your sql. I think.

```
$q1 = "SELECT u.address AS address, u.postcode AS postcode, u.town AS town, u.telnumber, u.mail, b.bookid AS bookid, b.name AS name, b.author AS author, s.duration AS duration from status s, book b, user u WHERE s.bookid = b.bookid AND s.borroweruserid = u.userid AND s.borroweruserid = '".$myuserid."'";
```